# Why python request return html file instead of excel?

Tags: python, html, excel, python-requests

I want to download excel file from this link via python
https://www.tfex.co.th/tfex/historicalTrading.html?locale=en_US&symbol=S50Z21&decorator=excel&series=&page=4&locale=en_US&locale=en_US&periodView=A

Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.tfex.co.th/tfex/historicalTrading.html?locale=en_US&symbol=S50Z21&decorator=excel&series=&page=4&locale=en_US&periodView=A'

resp = requests.get(url)
with open('file.xls','wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

But the file.xls is instead a html text file.
file.xls looks like this.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYmeA.png)

I've tried add headers

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But it didn't help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you hit an endpoint that's named `historicalTrading.html`, wouldn't you expect to get HTML content back?

Comment: @TheFool if you open it in a browser it downloads an excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Found a way using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

url = r'https://www.tfex.co.th/tfex/historicalTrading.html?locale=en_US&symbol=S50Z21&decorator=excel&series=&page=4&locale=en_US&periodView=A'

# read into HTML tables
tables = pd.read_html(url)
# merge HTML tables
merged = pd.concat(tables)
# Write tables to excel file
merged.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Hope this helps :)

**Ignore below, this was before edit:**

I know this is still problematic depending on your downstream application. The code below does seem to still download it into a HTML format, but this format can be opened in excel regardless.

```
import requests
url = r'https://www.tfex.co.th/tfex/historicalTrading.html?locale=en_US&symbol=S50Z21&decorator=excel&series=&page=4&locale=en_US&periodView=A'

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
excel_url = r.url
open('out.xls', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

When I open this in excel I get a warning, and click okay.

[screenshot of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoS5F.png)